# Как возвращать из функции время каждую секунду?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

Я хочу отобразить на странице текущее время, так чтобы оно обновлялся каждую секунду.Проблема в том, в функции return не возвращает обновленное время

```
function showTime(){

    const date = new Date();
    const currentTime = date.toLocaleTimeString();
    setTimeout(showTime, 1000);
    //console.log(currentTime); работает корректно
    return currentTime;
}
showTime();
```

Comment: а куда оно должно возвращать?

Comment: У меня есть еще HTML-код, нужно время отобразить в классе time. Вот код

Comment: const timeElement=document.querySelector('time');
timeElement.textContent=showTime();

Comment: так и отображайте данные прям в функции

Comment: Функция которую я написала, обновляет время только при перезагрузке странице, а мне нужно чтобы время обновляlся каждую секунду.

Answer (score 0):

Не понимаю, чем вам не угодил такой подход (делать вывод значения прямо в функции):

```js
function showTime(){
    const date = new Date();
    const currentTime = date.toLocaleTimeString();        
    const timeElement = document.querySelector('time'); 
    timeElement.textContent = currentTime; 
    
    setTimeout(showTime, 1000);
}
showTime();
```

```html
<time></time>
```

может быть сделать вот так, чтобы отделить функцию взятия даты  и рендер

```js
let timer = document.querySelector('time');

function getTime() {  
    return (new Date()).toLocaleTimeString();        
}

function renderTime(timer){    
    timer.textContent = getTime();     
    setTimeout(renderTime, 1000, timer);
}
renderTime(timer);
```

```html
<time></time>
```

Comment: В задании дано, что методы поиска элементов в функции включать не нужно: все найденные элементы вместе с присвоенными им переменными нужно оставлять в начале кода.

Comment: Можете вынести их из функций....и передавать элемент как аргумент в функцию, если угодно.....вы должны понять.... что `let something = showTime()` не сможет вернуть значение бесконечное количество раз......как только что-то было присвоено переменной, код идёт дальше...ниже..... поэтому в случае с таймером какой-то код обязательно придётся внести внутрь функции..... как минимум можете сделать так как я описал в начале комментария

Comment: Во втором примере в ответе я написал такой вариант...